# How to add two string in multiple lines?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsstring

I have two string which i want to display in my table view in two lines but in same cell. These strings are separate from the mail cell text label. So apart from cell label i want to add two more string on the right side of the cell in multiple lines.

```
NSString * string1 = @"Up";
NSString * string2 = @"Down";
```

I want them to be displayed like this:

```
UP
Down
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add UILabels as subviews to your cells, or better, subclass UITableViewCell to customize it.

Everything is explained in detail in the [TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html), especially the chapter "A closer look at TableView cells" where Apple explains multiple possibilities to customize your TableView cells and post code samples and pictures about the concept.

*(Actually you should consider reading the whole programming guide that explains a lot about tableviews, it's worth reading like every Apple Programming Guides)*

Comment: I don't think its working forget about the table view. Just tell me if there is a way we can display two strings in multiple lines.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Customizing the TableView cell as explained. Did that tons of times myself. It's simple and consists only of adding two UILabels to you cell, that's easy and the standard way to do it.

Comment: You can also set the numberOfLines property of a UILabel to 2 then affect it's text to the the strings separated by \n… but you still will need some customization for your label to be on the right and with the font and size you expect.

Comment: Actually i cannot make my class as subclass of UITableViewCell because its already inherited from some other class.